# In Django templates, `Context` is a stack. What for?

Tags: python, django, templates

Django docs [say](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#pop) that `Context` object is a stack:

```
from django.template import Context
c = Context()
c['a'] = 1
c.push() # Make a new Context level
c['a'] = 2
print(repr(c)) # [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
```

Also the docs say

> Using a Context as a stack comes in handy in some custom template tags

However, there's no example for that. My suggestion: it's useful to render a subtemplate with a clean context ; but one can just use a new empty `Context()` object instead.

So, what's the use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case would be scoping, for example in loops and template inheritance.

Comment: Oh, really. I thought of it but the docs say nothing of such behavior :) SO: when a key is missing in the upper scope — it's searched further. When a key is added/modified — these changes does not affect lower scopes.